# Alinear imagen no funciona

Tags: html, css

Necesito poner la imagen a la derecha, pero por más que le ponga que se mueva hacia ahí, se queda donde está.

He probado con `text-align: right` en el css, con `align="right"` dentro de la etiqueta `img`, `align-items: right` en el css, y es que no hace nada.

Ya no sé qué más probar

```css
* {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

body {
 color: #FF0000;
 font: 14px Sans-Serif;
 padding: 50px;
 background: #eee;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0 12px 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: strong;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0 12px 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: strong;
 font-size: 17px;
}

.imagenICO {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 position: absolute;
 text-align: right;
}

#container {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position: relative;
 background: white; 
}

table {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

th {
 background-color: #FF0000 ;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}

th small {
 font-size: 9px; 
 color: black;
}

td, th {
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

 <img src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fbd9996e24bc43bb8f.png" class="imagenICO">

 <h1>Titulo</h1>
 <p>Hola</p>
 <p>Hola</p>

 <table class="sortable">
     <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Nombre Fichero</th>
   <th>Tipo</th>
   <th>Tamaño</th>
   <th>Fecha de modificación</th>
  </tr>
  
     </thead>
  </table>
</body>
```

Comment: Podrías probar con `float: right`, pero tienes un posicionamiento absoluto que la va a fijar a 150x150. Con eso se va a mantener ahí fija independientemente del resto de código, a no ser que lo sustituyas

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Al tener la imagen posicionada en `absoluto` puedes usar las propiedades: `top`, `right`, `bottom` y `left` para colocar a tu elemento en la posición que desees respecto al primer ancestro con `position: relative`.

En tu caso la propiedad `text-align` no te serviría para posicionar la imagen. En su lugar puedes usar `right: 0px`

```css
* {
 padding:0;
 margin:0;
}

body {
 color: #FF0000;
 font: 14px Sans-Serif;
 padding: 50px;
 background: #eee;
}

h1 {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0 12px 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: strong;
}

p {
 text-align: center;
 padding: 20px 0 12px 0;
 margin: 0;
 font-weight: strong;
 font-size: 17px;
}

.imagenICO {
 width: 150px;
 height: 150px;
 position: absolute;
 right: 0px;
}

#container {
 box-shadow: 0 5px 10px -5px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
 position: relative;
 background: white; 
}

table {
 background-color: #FFFFFF;
 border-collapse: collapse;
 width: 100%;
 margin: 15px 0;
}

th {
 background-color: #FF0000 ;
 color: #FFF;
 cursor: pointer;
 padding: 5px 10px;
}

th small {
 font-size: 9px; 
 color: black;
}

td, th {
 text-align: left;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container">

 <img src="https://www.stickpng.com/assets/images/580b57fbd9996e24bc43bb8f.png" class="imagenICO">

 <h1>Titulo</h1>
 <p>Hola</p>
 <p>Hola</p>

 <table class="sortable">
     <thead>
  <tr>
   <th>Nombre Fichero</th>
   <th>Tipo</th>
   <th>Tamaño</th>
   <th>Fecha de modificación</th>
  </tr>
  
     </thead>
  </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 2):

estuve revisando tu código y veo que el posicionamiento que le estás dando a la imagen es absoluto, lo que quiere decir que que le estás asignando una posición exacta dentro de tu otra etiqueta div.
Para hacer cambios en ese posicionamiento debes usar las propiedades **top, right, bottom y left.**

Para lo que tu necesitas podrías probar con esto que intenté hacer con el código css.

```
.imagenICO {
width: 150px;
height: 150px;
position: absolute;
top: 20px;
right: 20px;}
```

Puedes jugar con las propiedades que te mencioné anteriormente con este tipo de posicionamiento. Con respecto a la propiedad que usaste "text-align" no te servirá ya que es una propiedad especifica para la alineación horizontal del texto en un elemento.

Te dejo este [enlace](https://uniwebsidad.com/libros/css/capitulo-5/posicionamiento-absoluto) para que puedas leer un poco más acerca del posicionamiento absoluto de elementos.